# Can't get an image to load to a webpage using PHP with MySQl

Tags: php, mysql

There's a couple questions I need to answered. The first is that I can't o get images from MySQL to populate when I log into the `loggedin.php` page. All I'm getting is a broken link.  I've seen people asking this question, but I've done my page in such a way that when I try to do it the way I've seen, I can't get it to work correctly.

Second, in my `$UpdateQuery`, I do not succeed to change the image  at all. I've looked all around for that and all I found was a YouTube video that didn't really help me.

Thanks in advanced.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS pulled from Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme pulled from Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Personal Sylesheet--> 
    <link href="MandelsCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Form to add new images into the database -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 align="center">Add Images</h1>
    <form class="form-signin" action ="loggedin.php" method = "post">
        Image Name: <input  class="form-control" type="text" name ="name"><br />
        Image Description: <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="description"><br />
        Picture: <input class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" type="file" name="image"><br />
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" type="submit" name ="submit" value="Insert New Image">
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <h1 align="center">Update Images</h1>

    <!--PHP to add new images to DB -->
    <?php

        require("connect1.php");
        ob_start();
        session_start();

            $select = "SELECT * FROM images";
            $myData = mysqli_query($connect, $select);

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image,image_name,description) VALUES('$_POST[image]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[description]')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        };
?>
    <?php

            $select = "SELECT * FROM images";
           $myData = mysqli_query($connect, $select);

     while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
        { 

    ?>

    <form class="form-signin" action ="loggedin.php" method = "post">
            Image Name: <input class="form-control" type="text" name ="name" value= <?php echo $record['image_name'] ?> > 
            <br />
            Image Description: <input class="form-control" type="text" name ="description" value= <?php echo $record['description'] ?> >
            <br />
            Picture: <input class="form-control" type="file" name ="image"  <?php echo $record['image'] ?>>
        <img name = "image" src =  <?php echo $record['image'] ?> >
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name ="hidden" value= <?php echo $record['image_name'] ?> > 
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-bloc" type="submit" name ="update" value ="Update Information">
            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-bloc" type="submit" name ="delete" value ="Delete">
        </form>
        <br />
        <br />



    <?php


         if (isset($_POST['update']))

         {
                   $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
        echo $imageData;
            $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE images SET image_name ='$_POST[name]', image = '$_FILES[image]', description='$_POST[description]'  WHERE image_name='$_POST[hidden]'";


                    mysqli_query($connect, $UpdateQuery);
         }


         if (isset($_POST['delete']))

         {

            $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM images WHERE image_name='$_POST[hidden]'";
            mysqli_query($connect, $DeleteQuery);
         }



        }
 mysqli_close($connect);
    ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this could be a problem: UPDATE images SET image_name ='$_POST[name]', image = '$_FILES[image]', description='$_POST[description]'  WHERE image_name='$_POST[hidden]'  try to echo that and see what you get

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot just pass $_FILES[image] to the db.

Comment: EDIT: Apparently I messed up the original time i put POST in because I just added it and it will update the DB now. The problem remains now that the image just isn't showing up.

Comment: Double check the path on your image.

Comment: Check the page source, and echo the var which holds your image location and filename to page (ie not in a link or html).

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting undefined index errors, so hopefully I can figure it out from here. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the picture with `image = '$_FILES[image]'` ! Try moving the picture with `move_uploaded_file($file , $targetpath)` in a folder and save the name of image in DB!